# Black screen after reboot on fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I just installed  Ubuntu 14.04 to try Linux. I am not familiar with linux structure or command line use. System:Gigabyte 8I915P Intel 3G  cpu 2G Ram.
Seemed to install OK but on reboot Ubuntu screen flashed purple and then black screen. It seems as if there is something there but not visible. I used the i386 version for install.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be tedious, it never hurts to reinstall. Also, make sure you are on a 32 bit system. If you are in windows, go into the about page to check.